# Changing the default PHP extensions for a new PHP version in IIS

Tags: php, iis, web-platform-installer

We use PHP on IIS, the initial install was via Web Platform Installer but to keep up with the current PHP releases I manually install new releases then use PHP Manager to switch IIS to the new version.  This process works pretty well except that IIS seems to have a default list of extensions which are automatically enabled when I install a new version; where is this list stored and can I change it?

The problem is that it includes old extensions like mysql which are no longer even present in PHP 7, so when I switch to a new version I immediately get an error until I have disabled the obsolete extension.

Comment: The reality is that PHP Manager for IIS has been a dead project for a while. You can modify it to meet your requirements, as it is open source.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of that

Comment: I took over the project, so may investigate this later, https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/issues/14

Comment: Fixed and will be in 2.0 final release.